# get the content moderation value on node update

Tags: 8, hooks, workflows

The module content moderation has been activated and a custom workflow added to a content type.
On editing content, when selecting a content moderation state then clicking on save, I would like to programmatically save that value in a variable.

`$mod` in that code doesn't display the latest values for moderation state chosen on update.

I wonder if what I get is the default revision value (as configured for a state, *Révision par défaut Quand le contenu atteint cet état il devrait devenir la révision par défaut; ceci est implicite pour les états publiés.*)  but it is definitely not the latest revision value.

```
function my_hook_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() !== 'node') {
    return;
  }

  $content_id = $entity->id();
  $content = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($content_id);       

  $mod=$content->get('moderation_state')->getValue();        
  var_dump($mod);
  die();
}
```

How do I get the latest value of content moderation on node update?

Comment: So far all you've stated are facts. What's the question? Is it "why does `$mod` not have a value?"

Comment: the question if unclear is how to get the latest value of content moderation on node update

Comment: I think what he meant is the transition towards the latest state. As in: You're editing a draft and setting the draft to published then saving, perhaps he wants the published state in the update process.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: I think you're getting the current revision moderation state value, what you need is to load  the latest revision of the node, and then just get the moderation state value from there.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the version of the entity meant getting the last revision and allow to get the correct value

```
function my_hook_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {    
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() !== 'node') {
    return;
  }

 $current_entity_lang = $entity->get('langcode')->value;
 $translated_entity = $entity->getTranslation($current_entity_lang);
 $mod = $translated_entity->get('moderation_state')->getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the string such as "published" right away

```
$node->moderation_state->value;
```

While `$node->get('moderation_state')->getValue();` returns an array.